# Reading image info in Julia without loading the images

Tags: image, shell, imagemagick, julia

I am writing a program to process a series of images in Julia, like ImageMagick but with some things that `-evaluate-sequence` can't do. Before spending time loading the images, I would like to do a quick check to be sure they're all the same size, color depth, and color space. I can get this information from ImageMagic for one file like this:

```
identify -ping -format "%[G] %[depth] %[colorspace]" IMAGENAME.PNG
```

(or .JPG or anything else that IM will read).

Plan A was to use the ImageMagick.jl library, but after browsing the source, it looks like MagickWand always loads the image first.

Is there a way to use ImageMagick.jl (or some other Julia library) to get the information without loading the files? If not ...

Plan B was to fire off a series of calls to `identify` and process the results myself. I can verify that IM is present and loading because this works:

```
readstring(`identify --version`)
```

But:

```
cmd = "identify -ping -format '%[colorspace] %[depth] %[G]' MYIMAGE.JPG"
```

returns a string that, copied and pasted onto a command line, works just fine. But when I try in REPL:

```
cmd = "identify -ping -format '%[colorspace] %[depth] %[G]' MYIMAGE.JPG"
readstring(`$cmd`)
```

this is what happens:

```
ERROR: could not spawn `"identify -ping -format '%[colorspace] %[depth] %[G]' IMG_1382.JPG"`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
in _jl_spawn(::String, ::Array{String,1}, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Base.Process, ::Base.DevNullStream, ::Base.PipeEndpoint, ::Base.TTY) at ./process.jl:321
in #424 at ./process.jl:478 [inlined]
in setup_stdio(::Base.##424#425{Cmd,Ptr{Void},Base.Process}, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}) at ./process.jl:466
in #spawn#423(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./process.jl:477
in (::Base.#kw##spawn)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#spawn, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
in open(::Cmd, ::String, ::Base.DevNullStream) at ./process.jl:539
in read(::Cmd, ::Base.DevNullStream) at ./process.jl:574
in readstring at ./process.jl:581 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
in readstring(::Cmd) at /Applications/JuliaPro-0.5.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
```

What is causing the problem?

Plan C would be to do low-level reads of the files myself, but I really, really don't want to do that.

Comment: For plan 'A' use `pingimage` method to read image info without loading image data. For plan 'B' ensure Julia loads shell environment where `PATH` knows the location of ImageMagick's utilities.

Comment: I know IM is found because I do `readstring(\`identify --version\`)` first (edited question to reflect this), and that completes successfully. I would like to be able to do this for PNG, JPG, and TIFF at a minimum without loading separate libraries for each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Plan A

You can definitely use the ImageMagick library directly; you just have to use a `wand` yourself and call the un-exported `pingimage` method:

```
julia> wand = MagickWand()
ImageMagick.MagickWand(Ptr{Void} @0x00007f92e48fac00)

julia> ImageMagick.pingimage(wand, filename)

julia> getimagecolorspace(wand), getimagedepth(wand), size(wand)
("sRGB",8,(1873,1630))
```

### Plan B

This is failing because [command interpolation is special](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/running-external-programs/#interpolation). Every string you splice into a `` `cmd` `` object is an atomic part of the command. It takes a bit of getting used to, but it is absolutely wonderful to not need to worry about quoting.  So instead of building it up as a string, build it up as a command directly. Doing it this way means the command will always "just work", even when there's spaces and special shell characters in the filename.

```
julia> readstring(`identify -ping -format '%[colorspace] %[depth] %[G]' $filename`)
"sRGB 8 1873x1630"
```

Of course, using the library directly is much nicer since you don't need to do string processing.